Probability? calculation - how would I work this out?
A colleague asked me this question, and to be honest, I'm not even sure how to frame it as a calculation. I assume it's possible, but I can't see where to start:
For 100 grant applications per year
If we were getting a 6% grant success rate when we expect to get 10%
We then do something and the success rates go up to 10%
How many years would we need to see this 10% rate for to say this was a statistically significant success of the intervention?
edit:
If I understand @jginestet response, the following calculation in R suggests by the second year the probability is less than 5%:
> 1 - pbinom(9, 100, 0.06)
[1] 0.07753906
> 1 - pbinom(19, 200, 0.06)
[1] 0.01793497


This is basically a Binomial problem. So, let's start after just year 1. What is the probability (binomial) of getting 10 succeses or more! out of 100 trials, if the expected (assumed) probability is .06? Can you reject the null ($p_0=.06$)? Now try after 2 years; what is the probability (binomial) for observing 20 succeses or more! out of 200 trials? Can you now reject the null? Rinse, lather, repeat (but, fwiw, you will not need to go any further).

Thank you! I have posted what I think is the correct calculation based on this. Let me know if that is incorrect.

Think of it as a power/sample size problem, estimating the sample size required to detect a shift in mean from 6 to 10.  You can hack out a rough guess approximating the Binom(100, 0.06) and Binom(100, 0.1) distributions as normal distributions, choosing your favorite alpha and beta values.

I am not sure about B(100,.06) (and B(100,.1) being even approximately normal... Why not use the actual Binomial diustribution?
